# Putty Closes when connecting to Remote Linux Machine after entering password

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, redhat-satellite

When I try to Connect from Putty(Windows) to Remote Virtual Machine(RED HAT). Putty Closes suddenly. I look in the putty there no issues and IP address is able to ping in my command prompt.

Doubt: Does i need to made any configurations in my ssh_config and sshd_config files.

Comment: Try to configure your putty to [not to close window](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-closeonexit) and share an error here. If you have other access to your linux box you could also give some error message. Without it I doubt anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: can you tell how can i get error info in putty

Comment: In previous command I gave you a link to putty documentation. It tells what and where you should change, so putty won't close window on exit.

Comment: bash: cvs: command not found

Comment: Are you running such a command or [have it configured in putty](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-command)? Or maybe you have something in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` files?

Comment: I am just Connecting to vm linux machine to start some service through putty.Do i need to edit any script on vm

Comment: `bash: cvs: command not found` error message (which you entered) suggests that during your ssh session some command was started. It might be a `cvs` itself or some script that tried to use it. As you wrote that window closes just after login I guess that you have such command configured as `Remote command` in putty (again, link to docs provided in previous comment) or you have it in profile files on remote machine. I don't have more information to go further into your problem.

Comment: I can able to access it from vnc.

Comment: Did you check putty configuration in 'SSH' -> 'Remote command' field?

Comment: It is empty in Remote command field

Comment: Then I advice to check your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files (in your home directory) for usage of `cvs` command. Or simply install cvs if you know why it is called.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in my sshd_config file, at the last line of file "ForceCommand cvs server" was uncommented ... it may happened by accident in my sshd_config file, I comment it and restart the sshd daemon.